# What is the limit regarding $a$

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

What is the limit of :

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(ax) - \ln(1-2x)}{e^{ax}-1-2x-2x^{2}}$$

I did this with Maclaurin, because my exam is about solving these with MacLaurin.

Gave $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ax-\frac {(ax)^{2}}{3!} +2x +4x^{2}}{1+ax+(ax)^{2} -1-2x-2x^2} = \frac {a+2}{a-2}$$

The answer should be: $a = 2$, limit is $1/2$, 
$ a \neq 2$, limit is $1$

Comment: and so ? it's not indeterminate for $a\neq -2$

Comment: If you're just wanting to check your answer, [WolframAlpha](http://po.st/5fxPxL) is probably the more practical option...

Comment: Sorry wasn't so specific in my question but the answer is wrong. So I was wondering if you could help me and find the error and maybe give me tips :)

Comment: L'Hopital gives the same answer: $\frac{a+2}{a-2}$. When $a=2$, the limit is undefined. Where do you get that the "answer should be..."

Comment: Well I have a exam tomorrow so I am doing old exams with solutions. The solution is that  :/

Comment: It is probably more convenient to use L'Hopital than series here. When you substitute, you get $\frac{\sin(0)-\ln(1)}{e^0 - 1 - 0 - 0} = 0/0$. Apply L'Hopital once and substitute. Then you get $\frac{a \cos(0)+2/(1-0)}{a e^0 - 2 - 0} = \frac{a+2}{a-2}$. For $a=2$ the left- and right- limits disagree, so the limit does not exist (even as an infinite limit).

Comment: So I had right and Mr.Professor wrong?

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(ax)-\ln(1-2x)}{e^{ax}-1-2x-2x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ax-\frac{(ax)^3}{3!}+\cdots-[-2x-\frac{(2x)^2}{2}-\frac{(2x)^3}{3}+\cdots]}{1+ax+\frac{(ax)^2}{2!}+\frac{(ax)^3}{3!}+\cdots-1-2x-2x^2}$

$=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(a+2)x+2x^2+(\frac{8}{3}-\frac{a^3}{6})x^3+\cdots}{(a-2)x+(\frac{a^2}{2}-2)x^2+\frac{a^3}{6}x^3+\cdots}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(a+2)+2x+(\frac{8}{3}-\frac{a^3}{6})x^2+\cdots}{(a-2)+(\frac{a^2}{2}-2)x+\frac{a^3}{6}x^2+\cdots}$

$\displaystyle=\begin{cases} \frac{a+2}{a-2} &\mbox {, if } a\ne2 \\ \text{does not exist} &\mbox{, if } a=2\end{cases}$

Comment: But shouldn't it be - inside the right bracket of the numerator?

Comment: @Ara Yes, I realized I have a sign error in the numerator. -- Thanks